# Why is the max current of the Pololu TB67H420FTG motor driver different to the max current in the datasheet of the IC?

Tags: motor, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller, motordriver

Note I am a beginner :)

This website states that TB67H420FTG **motor driver** can deliver continuous 1.7 amps for each "channel" i.e. motor.  https://www.pololu.com/product/2999

However,
Looking at the TB67H420FTG **motor driver** datasheet https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1510/TB67H420FTG_datasheet_en_20170818.pdf

The constant PWM threshold can be calculated using this formula:[image]

Using the datasheet formula for dual control, if had a VREF value of 2 volts (which is typical according to the datasheet), I could provide 2 X 1.25 = 2.5 amps to each channel easily?

Why would this website: https://www.pololu.com/product/2999 state continuous current of 1.7amps when the datasheet shows a much higher max current of 4.5 amps can be achieved for each channel.

Comment: it is important to distinguish the correct names of the devices ... one is a `motor driver module`, the other one is a `motor driver IC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The datasheet makes it clear that in any circumstance the PEAK current shall not be higher than 4.5A.

- The peak current is not a continuous current.
- It depends on PCB area size and number of copper layers, as well the thickness of copper layers
- It depends on environment temperature

Therefore the device has been tested and it was found out that it can handle max. 1.7A continuous current, probably at 25C ambient air without enclosure.